# WPF WebBrowser control how to disable shortkeys of IE?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

Hi all I have a problem I am using WPF WebBrowser control in application, and I need
to disable shortkeys of IE, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> etc
Is there a way to resolve this problem?
Help me please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

On the winforms WebBrowser you can also handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event and set `IsInputKey = true`. This gives you better control over which shortcuts/hotkeys to disable. This example illustrates how to disable Ctrl+N and Ctrl+O but let other hotkeys, like Ctrl+F and Copy/Paste enabled.

```
void browser_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.N || e.KeyCode == Keys.O) && e.Control)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}
```

`PreviewKeyDown` event does exist on the WPF version, but I have not tried the equivalent code. I changed to hosting the winforms `WebBrowser` in WPF since the WPF version was lacking in functionality.

Comment: the same ,use e.Handled = true;

Answer (score 2):

Setting the WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled property of the WebBrowser control to false should accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer it is OK for WinForms control but I am using WPF control

Comment: you can use the keydown event of webbrowser to wrap the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Adding final answer on how to disable certain shortcuts/hotkeys in WPF `WebBrowser` control.

Initialization:

```
Browser = new WebBrowser();
Browser.LoadCompleted += DocumentLoaded;
Browser.PreviewKeyDown += BrowserOnPreviewKeyDown;
```

Event handling:

```
private void BrowserOnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
    switch (key)
    {
        // disable F5
        case Key.F5:
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        // disable Ctrl + O, Ctrl + N, Ctrl + L
        case Key.O:
        case Key.N:
        case Key.L:
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            return;
        case Key.P: // Print dialog
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
            {
                // is handled, when printing is disabled
                e.Handled = !EnablePrintHotKey;
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

*Based on @curlyhairedgenius answer*